# How can I add "Organization" declaration into SP's metadata (Spring SAML)?

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

Is there any way to include the informations about the Organization into the generated SP's metadata with **Spring Security**? Because by default I can't see it included in the generated metadata XML.

### What I'm currently getting

I've tried to create a custom class `SAMLMetadataGenerator` which extends the framework's class `MetadataGenerator`, and then tried to *Override* the `buildExtensions` method in the following way:

```
public class SAMLMetadataGenerator extends MetadataGenerator {

   @Override
   protected Extensions buildExtensions(String entityBaseURL, String entityAlias) {
        super.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(true);
        Extensions extensions = super.buildExtensions(entityBaseURL, entityAlias);
        if (extensions != null)
            extensions.getUnknownXMLObjects().add(generateOrganization());

        return extensions;
   }

   private Organization generateOrganization() {
    OrganizationBuilder organizationBuilder = new OrganizationBuilder();
    Organization organization = organizationBuilder.buildObject();

    OrganizationNameBuilder organizationNameBuilder = new OrganizationNameBuilder();
    OrganizationName organizationName = organizationNameBuilder.buildObject();
    organizationName.setName(new LocalizedString("ACME", "en"));

    OrganizationDisplayNameBuilder displayNameBuilder = new OrganizationDisplayNameBuilder();
    OrganizationDisplayName organizationDisplayName = displayNameBuilder
            .buildObject();
    organizationDisplayName.setName(new LocalizedString("ACME Corporation", "en"));

    OrganizationURLBuilder organizationURLBuilder = new OrganizationURLBuilder();
    OrganizationURL organizationURL = organizationURLBuilder.buildObject();
    organizationURL.setURL(new LocalizedString("http://spid.serviceprovider.it", "it"));

    organization.getOrganizationNames().add(organizationName);
    organization.getDisplayNames().add(organizationDisplayName);
    organization.getURLs().add(organizationURL);
    return organization;
   }
}
```

This way the produced SP's metadata is then:

```
<md:EntityDescriptor
    xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="com_xegiy84105_spring_sp" entityID="com:xegiy84105:spring:sp">
    <!-- Other things here -->
    <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:Extensions>
            <idpdisco:DiscoveryResponse
                xmlns:idpdisco="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:idp-discovery-protocol" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:idp-discovery-protocol" Location="http://localhost:8091/DM-WEB/saml/login?disco=true" index="0"/>
            <md:Organization>
                <md:OrganizationName xml:lang="en">ACME</md:OrganizationName>
                <md:OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="en">ACME Corporation</md:OrganizationDisplayName>
                <md:OrganizationURL xml:lang="it">http://spid.serviceprovider.it</md:OrganizationURL>
            </md:Organization>
        </md:Extensions>
        <!-- Other things here -->
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

### How it should really be

But the "Organization" block should be inserted without being surrounded by `<md:Extensions/>` and it should be placed as a **direct child** of the `<md:EntityDescriptor/>` block similiar to the **following snippet**:

```
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    entityID="https://spid.serviceprovider.it"
    ID="_0j40cj0848d8e3jncjdjss...">
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        [...]
    </ds:Signature>
    <md:SPSSODescriptor
        protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
        AuthnRequestsSigned="true"
        WantAssertionsSigned="true">
        [...]
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
    <md:Organization>
        <OrganizationName xml:lang="it">Service provider</OrganizationName>
        <OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="it">Nome service provider</OrganizationDisplayName>
        <OrganizationURL xml:lang="it">http://spid.serviceprovider.it</OrganizationURL>
    </md:Organization>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

What is the correct way to achieve this goal?
Thanks.

Comment: extensions.getUnknownXMLObjects().add(generateOrganization()); that's why it's in the extensions. Add it to super instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's in the extensions is this:

```
extensions.getUnknownXMLObjects().add(generateOrganization());
```

according to the [docs for MetadataGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/saml/metadata/MetadataGenerator.html) you can use:

```
generateMetadata()
```

which returns an [EntityDescriptor](https://javadoc.io/static/org.opensaml/opensaml-saml-api/3.4.3/org/opensaml/saml/saml2/metadata/EntityDescriptor.html), which you can add the org to:

```
setOrganization(generateOrganization());
```

Comment: Hi @codebrane .. thanks! That was the thing I needed to generate the SP's metadata correctly.